# Design Logic App using service bus queue for notifying the Malicious content after the AV scan of file from Server

Tags: azure, service, queue, cloud

Please help on this if whether any script needs to defined inside the Service bus queue for the below and the design.
Design Logic App using service bus queue for notifying the Malicious content after the AV scan of file from Server.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the logic app should do ? Like just send an email or also trigger antimalware scan ?

Comment: Hi Thomas,Thanks for the response below for your kind reference- Please can I have quick reply for this scenario:- I'm sending file through one source file path and file name in the azure file share which is in turn mounted to the azure Linux server to a path. - continuation below...,

Comment: Now I am designing a logic app where when a message sent to the service bus queue of the failure service bus queue created and when the message sent to 
it using a JSON format from the python code 
here the logic app gets triggered based on the input param like filename and path  now when scan from the server gets completed from the av server.,
i.e also the file share server as well, the malicious content is identified in the file and it should get the meta data driven
 from the table storage of the email id and notify the recipient on all the param like file path and file name....